# What will be the value for wal_recycle while using streaming replication in PostgreSQL 12?

Tags: postgresql-12

wal_recycle is new setting in PostgreSQL 12. By default it is ON. What will be the value for wal_recycle  while using streaming replication in PostgreSQL 12 ?

Comment: [Quote from the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/runtime-config-wal.html#GUC-WAL-RECYCLE) "*On COW file systems, it may be faster to create new ones, so the option is given to disable this behavior*" (COW = Copy On Write)

Comment: I'm still not clear what value we need to set if streaming replication is configured.

Comment: This has nothing to do with streaming replication, rather with the filesystem you are using

Comment: ok. So in PostgreSQL 12 this is a new setting and will not affect the streaming replication. Default value for this setting is ON on my server. And will keep it as it is.                                      
 Thanks.